# I do not understand the code that reverses a string using streams

Tags: java, lambda

Please give an explanation for the below code reversing the String with streams:

```
public static String reverse(String test) { 
    return IntStream.range(0, test.length()) 
                    .map(i -> test.charAt(test.length() - i - 1)) 
                    .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, c) -> sb.append((char) c), StringBuilder::append) 
                    .toString(); 
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at my edit and revise it. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The method can be broken down into 5 key areas:

```
public static String reverse(String test) {
        return IntStream.range(0, test.length())
                .map(i -> test.charAt(test.length() - i - 1))
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, c) -> sb.append((char) c), StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();
    }
```

On line 1, the String is passed into the method to be returned in the reverse order. For example, String test can be equal to "world"

On line 2, a stream of numbers are passed into the stream  which are as long as the String that is passed in. If test was equal to "world", the stream of numbers would be 0,1,2,3,4

On line 3, the numbers are mapped into the number from the back of the String which they are present. So number 0 is mapped into the character that is test.length (5) -i (0) -1. So number 0 is mapped into character at point 4. This is equal to "d". This is done for all the other numbers so 0 = d, 1 = l, 2 = r, 3 = o, 4 = w.

On line 4, a new Stringbuilder is created and each character is appended into the StringBuilder so it will add the characters as they come (d -> l -> r -> o -> w)

Lastly on line 5, the StringBuilder is returned using the toString() method.

As a result, the String "world" is reversed.

Comment: My Actual Doubt was in 5th Line Why We are doing Append two times in collect method.Collect Method is Taking this Parameters<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)

Comment: The first argument is the Mutuable object to be created (StringBuilder)

The second argument defines how each object in the stream (character) is going to be accumulated. Each character is appended into a StringBuilder instance. 

Finally, all the StringBuilders are combined by being appended upon each other.

The toString() takes all the combined StringBuilders and returns a single String